# Ain't no mountain high enough... - what is the tallest LEGO piece?

Tags: piece-information, size, records

What is the tallest LEGO single piece ever?

**Clarifications**

- It must **not** necessarily be a purchasable block.
- By tallest, I mean a piece *preferably* in its natural standing position, although also the lying longest pieces could go, provided their exceptionality fits the requirements...
- No restrictions on the materials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> No restrictions on the materials.

Well then, probably a component to the old wooden furniture LEGO used to produce, like these:

### [5003483 - 3-Seat Playtable Creative Play Station Center Pack Duplo](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=5003483)

Or the similarly designed [4509g - 3-Seat Playtable](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=4509g), [5004063 - 3-Seat Playtable](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=5004063), or [5003468 - 3-Seat Playtable Creative Play Station Center Pack](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=5003468).

[image]

### [IF-LTW2C - Activity Table and Chair Set](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=IF-LTW2C)

[image] [image]

They did require some assembly, so I'm not sure if any parts stood up on their own, but you could probably balance a table leg for example.